# Getting more than 13 last line on test error in Travis-CI

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

When I build an R package under TravisCI, the last 13 lines are printed out when a test fails. To debug a problem that only occurs under Travis, I need more lines.

Where can I set the number of lines shown in the log?

Added later:

https://github.com/hadley/testthat/commit/f037f463edcccd403502308fd86e32914c6d0d0f

Looks like it is a testthat feature, but I did not understand how to switch it off.

Comment: See Dirk's answer below; looks like it is not a feature of Travis

Comment: I am not sure, but I fail to find the feature in the (extensive) [documentation for Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Customizing-the-Build-Step)

Comment: And just to claridy: "not a feature of Travis" is not how I would word it.  Maybe "unavailable in the official Travis R setup" but still available if you go via (highly customizable, if you care) scripts as we all did at first.  And what I still do for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the "number of trailing lines of test output to reproduce in the log" when running `R CMD check` can be controlled by the environment variable `_R_CHECK_TESTS_NLINES_` which is documented in the R Internals [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Tools).

The default value of this environment variable is 13, but if set to 0, "all lines except the R preamble are reproduced".

This answer was prompted by a blog post covering this solution by [Yihui Xie](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/last-13-lines-of-output/).

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this at the end of your `travis.yml`:

```
after_failure:
  - ./run.sh dump_logs
```

(where `run.sh` is my [maintained fork of the initial R-Travis](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r-travis/)).

That script (just like the `travis.sh` it came from) have this code:

```
DumpSysinfo() {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    echo "Dumping system information."                                                                                                                                                                              
    R -e '.libPaths(); sessionInfo(); installed.packages()'                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

DumpLogsByExtension() {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                                          
        echo "dump_logs_by_extension requires exactly one argument, got: $@"                                                                                                                                        
        exit 1                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    extension=$1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    shift                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    package=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.Rcheck" -type d)                                                                                                                                                          
    if [[ ${#package[@]} -ne 1 ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                             
        echo "Could not find package Rcheck directory, skipping log dump."                                                                                                                                          
        exit 0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    for name in $(find "${package}" -type f -name "*${extension}"); do                                                                                                                                              
        echo ">>> Filename: ${name} <<<"                                                                                                                                                                            
        cat ${name}                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    done                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

DumpLogs() {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    echo "Dumping test execution logs."                                                                                                                                                                             
    DumpLogsByExtension "out"                                                                                                                                                                                       
    DumpLogsByExtension "log"                                                                                                                                                                                       
    DumpLogsByExtension "fail"                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

and I am sure you can take it from here.  The 'new new' Travis surely has a setup for it too.

Comment: I was so happy to move to fast and lean container base builds. Or could I use run.sh somehow?

Comment: I decided for reason detailed on the link above to NOT move to the containers, and I do have the feature you need.  Your call.  I _assume_ the new setup can also run a simple `cat ${filename}` but I don't use that so I cannot give you a copy and paste ready answers.  Worst case create a new branch using `run.sh` til you have your problem licked.